# Are independent (micro)services a paradox?

Tags: rest, web-services, service, architecture, microservices

Ideas about microservices:

- Microservices should be functionally idependent
- Microservices should specialize in doing some useful work in a domain they own
- Microservices are intended to communicate with each other

I find this these ideas to be contradictory.

Let me give a hypothetical business scenario.

I need a service that executes a workflow that has a step requiring auto-translation.

My business has an auto-translation service. There is a RESTful API where I can POST a source language, target language and text, and it returns a translation. This is a perfect example of a useful standalone service. It is reusable and completely unaware of its consumers.

Should the workflow service that my business needs leverage this service? If so, then my service has a "dependency" on another service.

If you take this reasoning to the exteme, every service in the world would have every functionality in the world.

Now, I know you're thinking we can break this dependency by moving out of resquestion-response (REST) and into messaging. My service publishes a translation request message. A translation response message is published when the translation is complete and my service consumes this message. Ok, but my service has to freeze the workflow and continue when the message arrives. It's still "waiting" even if the waiting is true async waiting (say the workflow state was persisted and the translation message arrives a day later). This is just a delayed request-response.

Comment: You can use [Uber Cadence Workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55486360/1664318) for such long running services orchestration.

Answer (score 1):

For me personally, "**independent**" is a quality that applies to **multiple dimensions**. It may not be independent from runtime perspective, but it can be independent from **development**, **deployment**, **operations** and **scalability** perspectives.

For example, **translation service** may be independently developed, deployed, operated by another team. At the same time they can scale **translation service** independently from your **business workflow service** according to the demand they get. And you can scale **business workflow service** according to your own demand (of course downstream dependencies come in play here, but that's a whole another topic)