# Is it possible to use Apache Airflow for choreography tasks without the scheduler?

Tags: java, python, workflow, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to develop a choreography architecture using the Apache Airflow Framework, but I don't want the DAGs to run in a scheduled way.

I read that the Apache Airflow framework can be used for service choreography. But I don't need any scheduling, I just need the framework to get a choreography between the nodes of a workflow.

Is it possible to use Apache Airflow without the scheduler? Is there any other framework (Java or Python) that you recommend me for this?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly create unscheduled DAGs

```
schedule_interval=None
```

You'll have to have the scheduler running to execute the task though, which you do like this:

```
airflow trigger_dag my-dag
```

As for alternatives, I suppose it all depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Most of the big choreography solutions have some scheduling built into the run-time. Apache Beam doesn't, but that's more specifically for data transformation and stream processing.

The closest thing might be luigi: https://github.com/spotify/luigi.  It's a python project that allows you to choreograph tasks like AirFlow.  It seems not to have a scheduler.  It also seems to have a much simpler UI.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your comment, Robert!!!

I need to know if there is any way to create a choreography architecture using Apache Airflow. How can I make each step of the DAG generate an event and it remains in a queue (JMS) that it's listening for the following step and it's activated when it finds the data? Is it possible with Apache Airflow?

Comment: I think you should ask another question!

Answer (score 0):

[Uber Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/04_javaclient/) is perfect for service orchestration scenarios. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55486360/1664318) provides more info.